# Dual Monitors with HDMI not Working

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I have two external monitors: one I connect directly to a VGA port on my laptop, and one I convert to HDMI which connects to my laptop.  If either one, and only one, is connected to my laptop in either way then everything is okay - I get one display on my laptop screen and another on the connected monitor.  But, when I try to plug both in, only one works, which is the one that was plugged in first.

Here's my Displays settings with both plugged in:
[image]

The HP 19" is currently plugged into HDMI and working as a second monitor.  The Acer 19" is plugged into VGA and not working.  When I slide the slider to "ON" and click "Apply", a window flickers down one of the already on screens, disappearing at bottom, and then I get the error message "Failed to apply configuration: %s" along with "Timeout was reached"

How can I get both external monitors to work simultaneously?

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions mentioned [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1986131)?

Comment: I have the same issue and tips the link Owen Hines provided do not work